# WriteDump failed hresult: 0x00000000

Tags: .net-core, raspbian

I'm on raspian, and issue
dotnet-dump collect -p (processID Here)
And I'm getting

writing full to /home/UserID/core_date_time
WriteDump failed - HRESULT: 0X00000000

I've checked, and the process has -X permissions.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/65347

Comment: OK, so the dump isn't supported for single file apps - Oh joy

Answer (score 1):

If you get the SDK installed on the device, `createdump` can be used to dump single file apps.

```
curl -fsSL https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/scripts/v1/dotnet-install.sh | bash -s -- --no-path --install-dir ~/dotnet-sdk --channel 6.0
~/dotnet-sdk/dotnet tool install --tool-path ~/dotnet-sdk/tools dotnet-dump
DOTNET_ROOT=~/dotnet-sdk ~/dotnet-sdk/tools/dotnet-dump ps

# use the PID of your process
DOTNET_ROOT=~/dotnet-sdk ~/dotnet-sdk/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.4/createdump <pid>

# load the dump into dotnet-dump
DOTNET_ROOT=~/dotnet-sdk ~/dotnet-sdk/tools/dotnet-dump analyze /tmp/coredump.95680
```

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately - gave me an error like this when I tried to run `createdump`:
`[createdump] ptrace(ATTACH, 24) FAILED Operation not permitted
[createdump] Target process is alive`. Reading the comments on the original question and your answer more though, I'm realizing my app probably isn't a single-file app.